# Как передать двойные кавычки в форму

Tags: php

Добрый день. У меня есть форма с текстовым полем Input В это текстовое поле отправляется значение при нажатии на кнопку. Если в этом значении в строке есть двойные кавычки то кавычки удаляются, а так же удаляется всё что после кавычек. Например нужно передать в форму строку ООО "Инженерные системы", а передается просто ООО. Хочу всегда сохранять двойные кавычки (желательно и одинарные). Функция htmlcpecialchars не помогла. Что я делаю неправильно?

```
value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars("OOO "Инженерные системы" ", ENT_NOQUOTES) ;?>"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете объяснить, почему *вы запретили* функции преобразовывать любые кавычки и после этого удивляетесь что кавычки не были преобразованы?

Параметр `ENT_NOQUOTES` именно запрещает преобразование двойных кавычек.

```
value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars('OOO "Инженерные системы" ') ;?>"
```

сгенерирует нормальное представление HTML

```
value="OOO &quot;Инженерные системы&quot; "
```

Которое будет корректно распознано браузером и отображено пользователю.

Если вам понадобится преобразовывать так же и одинарные кавычки (например, если у вас параметр HTML в одинарных кавычках) - то вам нужно указать флаг `ENT_QUOTES`.

Comment: блин, неправильно понял, как работает функция.